# PDFBox why is the image not appearing in the PDF output?

Tags: java, netbeans, pdfbox

I have (I think) correctly followed the instructions from: https://memorynotfound.com/apache-pdfbox-add-image-pdf-document/

I am attempting to insert an image `logo.png`. The code runs and doesn't throw up any errors, but the resulting PDF does not contain an image! The text does appear as expected. Does anybody know why this is and how to fix it?
I'm using Java 8 in Apache NetBeans 11.

Thanks. Here's the code:

````
    public void generate(File samplefile) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        //Adding the blank page to the document
        //Repeat this next line for further pages
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);
        File dir = new File(ArdenRecord.sadd + "/Sample Reports");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        String fname = samplefile.toString().split("\\.")[0].split("\\\\")[2];
        File f = new File(ArdenRecord.sadd + "/Sample Reports/" + fname + ".pdf");
        File imfile = new File(ArdenRecord.sadd + "/logo.png");

        PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imfile.toString(), document);

        PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        PDRectangle mediaBox = page.getMediaBox();

        float startX = (mediaBox.getWidth() - pdImage.getWidth()) / 2;
        float startY = (mediaBox.getHeight() - pdImage.getHeight()) / 2;
        contents.drawImage(pdImage, startX, startY);

        contents.beginText();
        contents.newLineAtOffset(25, 700);
        contents.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(samplefile));

        String st;
        int n = 0;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (n < 4 || n > 20 && n < 30) {
                contents.showText(st);
                contents.newLineAtOffset(0, -18);
            }
            n++;
        }

        contents.endText();
        contents.close();

        document.save(f);
        document.close();

        Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
    }


}```
````

Comment: Please share the result PDF  file and the source image.

Comment: Also make sure you are using the latest version 2.0.17.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's nothing wrong with your code. I copy-pasted (removed `.split("\\\\")[2]` to get path right), compiled and tested it with PDFBox 2.0.17, OpenJDK 8, [this PNG file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Stackoverflow_icon.png) and the first chapter of [Lorem Ipsum](https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html) in a text file. See the result below (Adobe Reader screenshot).

[image]

At least you should try with a different PNG file.